# Perl LWP::UserAgent only reading first line of posted jpg file

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm sure this has been asked but I could not find a good question to my answer.  I've got two scripts, one makes a post using LWP::UserAgent and the other basically receives the data, in this case I'm just looking to write a file.  The file does get written but it can't be opened and the size is 1262 which leads me to believe only some of it is being read.

Here's what I'm doing (It's worth noting, I was uri/base64 encoding the file and passing everything via json, which was working, but my new task is the split the files out and pass everything as form params):

post script:

```
open (IMAGE, "./flower.jpg") or die "$!";
$raw_string1 = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$req->content("json_string=$json&file_1=$raw_string1");

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$res = $ua->request($req);
print $res->content;
```

Receiver script:

```
$cgi = CGI->new;
my $json_post = $cgi->param('json_string');
my $file_1 = $cgi->param('file_1');

open my $fh, '>', "$path/flower.jpg" or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $file_1;
close $fh;
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: hooray for random down vote!  I can provide more code, less code, better specifics about what I'm looking to do, but random down vote stinks.

Comment: How you you receive the `$file_1` variable?

Comment: Thanks for response.  I edited my above code to show in receiver script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you have an encoding problem. The solution is simple:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url, [
   json_string => $json,
   file_1      => $raw_string1,
]);
```

which is short for

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url,
   Content_Type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   Content => [
      json_string => $json,
      file_1      => $raw_string1,
   ]
);
```

It's far more typical to use `multipart/form-data` to upload files, though. And if you do, you can even let HTTP::Request load the file for you!

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url,
   Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
   Content => [
      json_string => $json,
      file_1      => [ 'flower.jpg' ],
   ]
);
```

CGI.pm will handle that no problem. See the section of the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) titled "PROCESSING A FILE UPLOAD FIELD".

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I got it working using your advice.  Many thanks!

Comment: I actually ended up going with this: my $url = "";                my $data = [json_string => $json, 'flower.jpg' => $raw_string1, 'fw4.pdf' => $raw_string2];

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$res = $ua->request(POST($url, $data));
print $res->content;

Comment: What a weird format. File names as identifiers?! With form-data, your fields can have both file names and file contents. Again, if you're designing a protocol, I recommend form-data.

Comment: Well, I am not allowed to base64 encode anything and just stick it in my json arrays, which is what I was originally doing.  So, I've been tasked with accepting a bunch of json arrays via a json param, then separately and as form params, a bunch of file name params.  The last key value pair of the each json array is a file name so I can identify and stick the file somewhere when handling each array.  In testing, I'm looking to be spinning through a few hundred of these.  I'm certainly open to suggestions.  Also, I did run into issues using your suggested syntax when trying to post to https.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help and your explanations allowed me to get a better grasp on things and get something working. *edit*  probably also fair to note, I will not be writing the post side, just the receiver script.

Answer (score 1):

You're not encoding the `$raw_string1` data before sticking it into the HTTP POST body. That means that if the data in `flower.jpg` includes a hex 0x26 byte (the `&` char) -- at position 1263, let's say -- then the POST data will look like this:

```
json_string={ ... JSON data ... }&file_1=...1262 bytes of raw JPEG data...&...more JPEG data...
```

... which means that anything parsing the form body for form variables will truncate `file_1` after 1262 bytes.

I'd recommend continuing to encode the `$raw_string1` data with base64 or something similar, even if you pass it through as its own POST variable rather than adding it to the JSON data.